# apache tiles - how to override an attribute from child template

Tags: jakarta-ee, attributes, tiles

The question is how can I override an attribute in tiles child template.

I've got two templates: base and child. This is a part of base layout - HTML head:

```
<title>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="title" />
    lyricsBase: <c:out value="${jukebox.name}" />
</title>
```

This is my tiles.xml:

```
<definition name="t.base" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="SomeTitle"/>
</definition>
[...]
<definition name="t.song" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/song.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" value="song.title"/>
</definition>
```

When I run my page, I get following HTML title: `song.title lyricsBase: xxx`. What code should I put into the child view to override the `title` attribute? I'm trying to make it ${song.title}, for example

```
<tiles:putAttribute name="title" value="${song.title}" />
```

...but it doesn't work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the value attribute but the expression attribute. In tiles3 I was having an issue with string values for put attributes without cascade being true... This assumes tiles3 (although most is applicable to most of tiles 2).

Following is untested:

```
<definition name="t.base" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" cascade="true" value="SomeTitle"/>
</definition>
[...]
<definition name="t.song" extends="t.base">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/song.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title"  cascade="true" expression="EL:song.title"/>
</definition>
```

Then `<tiles:insertAttribute name="title" />` should work as expected in your template.

Comment: expression (instead of value) solves the problem. Thanks!
By the way - why did you add "cascade" here? For me it worked without it.

Comment: As recent as last night I had a strange issue where I couldn't override a value without cascade being true for a string, it didn't affect templates... just the strings. If you didn't need to do it then that is perfect (really you shouldn't). You should only need cascade when defining inner templates... which was not my case either but for some reason adding it worked for me.