# How to set EL variable in Struts ValueStack

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tiles, ognl

I'm using Tiles to include a JSP on my page and I'm passing variables to it however I have no way of accessing the values I pass in Struts tag.

The only way I can think of is to add a EL value to the struts value stack. Any ideas on how to do this?

Page I'm inserting the JSP to:

```
<tiles:insertTemplate template="manage_requests_tab.jsp">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="page" value="p1" />
    <tiles:putAttribute name="pageSize" value="ps1" />
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

Page I'm including:

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="page" />
<tiles:importAttribute name="pageSize" />

<s:select name="page" id="pageSize" list="myList" listKey="value" listValue="label" />
```

Comment: What variables do you pass?

Comment: I'm passing Strings and objects to the included page.  I can access them outside of my struts tags fine.

Comment: What version of tiles? How are you passing the values to the page? Best show a side by side example of a struts2 tag not doing what you need while EL is able to do the same. Have you tried "#attr.var" in the struts2 expressions?

Comment: Something that occurred to me... is p1 and ps1 are values exposed they you don't want to use the value attribute of putAttribute tag but the expression attribute, also if this is tiles3 the expression will need to be prefixed "EL:", for a similar issue see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884304/apache-tiles-how-to-override-an-attribute-from-child-template/14884836#14884836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<s:set var="yourString2">${yourString}</set>` . After that you could reference `#yourString2` in the struts tags. if you need OGNL enforcement that add `%{#yourString2}`.